# Should I be concerned that my 2 year-old cannot pronounce sounds like "vee" and "fee"?

Tags: toddler, language-development, speech

Our first child had no problems speaking quite clearly.
However, our second child who is 2 years old
has trouble pronouncing sounds like "vee" and "fee".
For example, "vessel" becomes "bessel" and "Sophia" becomes "So-bee-ia".
Will this problem naturally correct itself as she grows older?

We know a friend who had a 4-year old who needed speech therapy,
though I do not know why he needed it and whether it was helpful.
How do we know if speech therapy is helpful or necessary?

Comment: How old is your child?

Comment: @Stephie A little over two years old. I added this detail in the question.

Comment: Sounds quite normal based on my experience of my own and other people's kids, but I'm not an expert - if you're concerned then can you get them assessed by a speech therapist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is a normal part of development for a two-year-old.

At 24 months a child should have about 70% accuracy of consonants, and by 36 months about 87% accuracy. Producing "b" instead of "f" is one example of a very common mistake a child of this age might make. Of course, if it seems like the accuracy is worse than 70%, or if the child does not seem to be improving in a few months, you may want to ask your pediatrician if speech therapy would be helpful.

---

**Technical Details:**

In technical terms, this kind of mistake is called producing a [stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_consonant) instead of a [fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fricative_consonant).

In the source paper, this is the top listed error for a 24 month old:

> Target fricatives/affricates are produced as stops

---

**Source**:

- [Early phonological development: Creating an
  assessment test - Carol Stoel-Gammon & A. Lynn Williams](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.3109/02699206.2013.766764)